# Always show scalebar in maps application (iOS 7/10)

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

i want to have the scalebar in the maps application (iOS7/10) to be always shown instead of when you zoom.

I searched trough the MapKit and came to a couple ScaleBar components, experimented a bit with no avail. Any body that knows how to make it always show up? Or change the fade duration?

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way before ios11, where you can use the `MKScaleView`; check out the "what's new in MapKit" session from WWDC2017